# MacBook Pro 13" SATA controller

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, sata

Does anyone know from a trusted source if the new MacBook Pro 13" (2012) has SATA III? 
On Google, some places said SATA II and couldn't find any info on Apple's site.

I also have one more question: if I connect an SSD (external case) on USB 3.0 will it be faster than a 5400 RPM on USB 3.0?

Comment: Or maybe any links to detailed specifications? Like cpu model etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Panther Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#5.2F6.2F7_Series_chipsets) has 6GBit/s ports. There is zero reason for Apple not to utilize them. I know this is not a perfect answer but this is all I can help.

SSD is much faster on USB 3.0 than a HDD. I would recommend reading [this](http://www.servethehome.com/usb-30-uasp-mode-performance-benefit-marketing-gimmick/) -- disregard the UASP part, it still gives you lot of benchmarks of running an SSD over USB 3.0. You can clearly see speeds well above 200 MB/s. There is no mechanical (notebook) drive that can do much more than 100 MB/s. Not the [Savvio](http://www.storagereview.com/ST973451SS.sr), not the [Spinpoint M8](http://www.storagereview.com/samsung_spinpoint_m8_review), nothing. It simply doesn't and cannot happen.

Edit: StorageReview [mentions](http://www.storagereview.com/best_drives) this [Hitachi DeskStar](http://www.storagereview.com/hitachi_deskstar_7k3000_3tb_review_hds723030ala640) being the fastest mechanical drive of all and it barely clears 150 MB/s.